# ShellExecuteEx print in VBA7 fails with access denied

Tags: windows, vba

We have VBA code in a Word macro that is used to download one or more documents, then print them using the Windows function [`ShellExecuteEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762154%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The code runs successfully in Word versions 97, 2000, 2003, 2007 and 2010 (32-bit) on Windows 2000, XP and 7 (32-bit and 64-bit).

But the call to `ShellExecuteEx` fails in 64-bit Word 2010 and 2013. We have updated the declarations for VBA7 (64-bit) as [documented on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee691831%28office.14%29.aspx) and [specified in the Win32API_PtrSafe file](http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=9970). For example:

```
#If VBA7 Then
Type SHELLEXECUTEINFO
    cbSize As Long
    fMask As Long
    hwnd As LongPtr
    lpVerb As String
    lpFile As String
    lpParameters As String
    lpDirectory As String
    nShow As Long
    hInstApp As LongPtr
    lpIDList As LongPtr
    lpClass As String
    hkeyClass As LongPtr
    dwHotKey As Long
    hIcon As LongPtr
    hProcess As LongPtr
End Type
Declare PtrSafe Function ShellExecuteEx Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteExA" _
    (sei As SHELLEXECUTEINFO) As Boolean
#End If
```

Usage is like this:

```
Dim bReturn As Boolean
Dim sei As SHELLEXECUTEINFO

With sei
    .cbSize = Len(sei)                  ' size of the object
    .fMask = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS    ' indicate that we want a hProcess back
    .hwnd = GetDesktopWindow()          ' the window we are calling from
    .lpVerb = "print"                   ' print the file
    .lpFile = lpFile                    ' the file we want to print
    .lpParameters = vbNullString        ' no parameters because its a file
    .lpDirectory = vbNullString         ' use the current dir as working dir
    .nShow = SW_HIDE                    ' state of the window to open
End With

bReturn = ShellExecuteEx(sei)

If bReturn Then
    WaitForSingleObject sei.hProcess, 5000
    CloseHandle sei.hProcess
    DoEvents
Else
    MsgBox "ShellExecuteEx failed with code: " & Err.LastDllError
End If
```

In 32-bit Word it works but in 64-bit Word the call to `ShellExecuteEx` always fails, returning 5 (SE_ERR_ACCESSDENIED). I have tried a range of flag values for `fMask` (including SEE_MASK_NOASYNC), tried not specifying a value for `hwnd` and different values for `nShow`, all with the same failed result.

The simpler [`ShellExecute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function works in both 32-bit and 64-bit Word but it is too inflexible. We want to use `ShellExecuteEx` because it is better when printing multiple documents: it gives us the ability to wait for the printing application (Word, Adobe Reader etc.) to be ready before sending another print request. Otherwise a print request fails if the application is not ready. (I tried simply waiting for a few seconds between print requests but that is not reliable.)

Why does `ShellExecute` print files but `ShellExecuteEx` fail with access denied?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use LenB instead of Len for 64 version OS.
The whole answer is here: http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/office-2010-x64-bit-qu-t1914261.html

Comment: `.cbSize = Len(sei)` should therefore be replaced by `.cbSize = LenB(sei)`